# Vimeo video with a custom unmute button using a video tag

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo-api

Currently I'm autoplaying a video on page load from a Vimeo direct link with am html5 `<video>` tag, this loads the video really quick on the page and the poster attribute also helps for perceived loading time:

```
<video id="video" poster="abc.jpeg?$staticlink$" playsinline muted>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/408636.hd.mp4?s=1552e499fb1e3aa2bf881c2ae762aa23988b5d&profile_id=175">
</video>
```

Now I want a way to unmute this using a button on the page, I've decided to do this i have to now use the Vimeo API [player.js](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js). See code below. The problem I'm having now is the `iframe` loads slow, and the vimeo API doesnt seem to have a poster attribute.

```
  <html>
    <div id="video" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
    <button class="volume">VOLUME ON</button>
  </html>

  <script>
    var volBtn = document.querySelector('.volume')

    var options = {
      url: "https://vimeo.com/123/456",
      loop: true,
      autoplay: true,
      background: true
    };

    var videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('video', options);

    volBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      videoPlayer.setVolume(1);
    })
  </script>
```

Is there a better way to do this, so we have both the video tags speed, and the iframes ability to unmute? Am I missing something obvious with the video or iframe tags? Can I maybe use a video tag with the Vimeo API?

Comment: You can't use the iframe implementation shown in https://github.com/vimeo/player.js? Do you need to add custom buttons?

Comment: i can use it, but the video takes a while to load, whereas just putting the vimeo direct link in <video> tags pops up on the screen extremely fast.. Iframe is too slow thats my problem

Comment: The vimeo video is NOT SHOWING with the HTML5 video tag, seems like it needs a Vimeo Pro account. Is that what you have? (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35055233/vimeo-video-player-in-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `player.js` for this. It's as simple as:

```js
const volBtn = document.querySelector('.volume')
const video = document.querySelector('#video')
volBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { videoEl.muted = false })
```

---

Also note that setting volume on a muted video with the help of `HTMLMediaElement` API leaves it muted. So this

```
volBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { videoEl.volume = 1 })
```

won't work as you expect. But this will

```
volBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 videoEl.muted = false
 videoEl.volume = 1
})
```

Comment: thanks i knew it was something simple (if you know how ha)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics), you can use the [`HTMLMediaElement.muted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/muted) property instead:

```js
// NOTE: cache the "video" element to prevent unnecessary re-selecting of the same object
const video = document.querySelector("#video");
document
  // select the volume button
  .querySelector(".volume")
  // bind a click event
  .addEventListener("click", () =>
    // unmute the video
    video.muted = false
  );
```

If you want to toggle the mute feature, use this [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) instead:

```js
() =>
  // toggle mute feature
  video.muted = !video.muted;
```

Good luck.